# inventory of Nifeliz sets

Tags: clone-brands, set-database, inventory

Is there any pre-made inventory that I can use to add the Nifeliz sets I bought to Rebrickable, as I do with the Lego branded sets?

I'm very surprised that a search for *Nifeliz* finds no posts, as they are getting some trending on Amazon.com now.

Comment: There is are reasons this won't be added to Rebrickable: sets are not made of LEGO, sets are using other people's work without crediting them. Based on this I assume MOC authors don't get paid as well, which doesn't add any respect to this "brand". So basically, you are asking "Lepin"-like sets/MOCs to be listed on Rebrickable.

Comment: Yes, given that it's been documented that Nifeliz steals Rebrickable designs its a bit of a provocative question to ask how to import Nifeliz inventories into Rebrickable... I am inclined to think this is a troll post...

Comment: NOT a troll... if nobody talks about it I would have no idea, right?  In-house credit seems to be mentioned in the ads for the ones I bought (two purple cars). Amazon.com is suggesting them and there is an Easter sale. Instead of finding _no posts_ why didn't I find that when I searched here before posting?

Comment: That is not how Amazon works. Suggestions and discounts like you mentioned are paid for by the seller or manufacturer. Add that it is well documented how simple Amazon's sales and review systems can be gamed, there is little reason to consider promotion on that site to be anything but paid placement using internal or external systems.

If you are an actual fan of this clone brand's products perhaps you would be best served by producing your own inventories.

Comment: @Closevoters: Note that while the question topic itself could be considered divisive or controversial, the question as a whole is objectively answerable (either by a positive confirmation or by explaining why a negative is likely).

Comment: @zovits, Contrary to what I earlier stated, I can't find any proof that they steal their designs from Rebrickable, it's more likely they contact people and pay them to retract their MOCs from public sources.
Nevertheless they certainly steal the element designs from LEGO and certainly do not make the proper licensing deals with the car brands.
As such I find their activities immoral and illegal and entertaining questions about these brands should be avoided.
Hence I like to see this question closed, but there seems to be no option to close a question about illegal activities...

Comment: @MichaelVerschaeve exactly that's what I mean. The spirit of the question might be repulsive, but it is a correctly formed question that can be answered appropriately and factually.

Comment: I suppose one can flag a question rather than vote to close it. It's the admins responsibility then whether or not they want to ban such content